# How to get the value from snack bar container using protractor script

Tags: protractor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN86I.jpg)How to retrieve the value from Snack bar container (used in angular application) from protractor script. There is a login page, when the wrong credentials given there is a popup used in the code using Snack bar container displaying the message `"Invalid credentials"` and Ok button. I want to capture the message invalid credentials. How to to do using the protractor script

Comment: kindly provide HTML of snackbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;   
 const snackBar = element(by.tagName('simple-snack-bar'));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(snackBar), 30000);
    element(by.tagName('simple-snack-bar')).getText().then(function (val) {
          expect(val).toEqual('Invalid credentials');
        });
```

Comment: in the 2nd line what is the EC refers to? may be this question is silly, plz help

Comment: EC refers to expected condition.           https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Comment: Thankyou very much............ got it worked........ gr8 help guys...............

Comment: hi, plz let me know how to to mark your answer is accepted, thorough comments, then please consider this comments as ACCEPTED

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.